# How to get all the enums in my project as JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, enums

I am building an ASP.NET Web API application and I need to provide an HTTP GET endpoint that returns all the enums in my project as shown in the following sample:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "EnumNameOne": {
                "attributeName1": value,
                "attribute2": value
            },
            "EnumNameTwo": {
                "attributeName1": value,
                "attribute2": value,
                "attributeName3": value
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I've got to use reflection, but how can I structure my classes to have the output as in the JSON payload above?

Comment: Where are your enums? Can you include that in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would do it as follows:

1. Make a generic `Result` class:

   ```
   class Result
   {
       public int Code { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }
       public object Data { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Make a method that can return the enums as a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`, for example:

   ```
   public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> GetAllEnums(Assembly assembly)
   {
       return assembly
           .GetTypes()
           .Where(t => t.IsEnum)
           .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t =>
               Enum.GetNames(t)
                   .Zip(Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<int>(), (Key, Value) => new { Key, Value })
                   .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
   }
   ```
3. Put the two together to get your result:

   ```
   var allEnums = GetAllEnums(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

   var result = new Result
   {
       Code = 200,
       Message = "OK",
       Data = new List<object> { allEnums }
   };
   ```

   This will give you the JSON structure shown in your question.  I should point out that the `List<object>` doesn't really add much value here, because it will always contain exactly one object.  I only added it to match the structure you said you needed.  It might make sense to leave it out unless you have a hard requirement for it, such as maintaining consistency with other API methods.

   ```
   var result = new Result
   {
       Code = 200,
       Message = "OK",
       Data = allEnums
   };
   ```

   With this change, the resulting JSON will look like this instead:

   ```
   {
       "code": 200,
       "message": "OK",
       "data": {
           "EnumNameOne": {
               "attributeName1": value,
               "attribute2": value
           },
           "EnumNameTwo": {
               "attributeName1": value,
               "attribute2": value,
               "attributeName3": value
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Here is a working demo (console app): https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXB4bF

---

If you wanted to get only the enums that are used by particular model classes, you could use this method instead:

```
static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> GetAllEnums(params Type[] types)
{
    return types
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Select(p => p.PropertyType)
        .Where(t => t.IsEnum)
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t =>
            Enum.GetNames(t)
                .Zip(Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<int>(), (Key, Value) => new { Key, Value })
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hdrcvj

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, is there away of getting the enums that were implemented in a specific model?, e.g. let's say there is enum_1 and enum_2 that's used in Model one only, how could i get those enums using reflection? Thank you very much for your answer!