# How to show enum string in jQuery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, enums, datatables

I'm new to datatables. I want to show string value of enum values but i can't.

**Table**

```
<table id="requestTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column dataTable no-footer" style="width:100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="sample_1_info">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Corporation</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

**GET**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        dataTable = $("#requestTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Request/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "RequestID", "render": function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Request")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-top:5px' onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                    },
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "150px"
                },
                { "data": "ProductName" },
                { "data": "ProductCorporation" },
                { "data": "ProductCategory" },
            ],
            "language": {

                "emptyTable": "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> Button"
            }
        });
    });
```

*this returns int value of enums. I want to show string value of them. I used this:*

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
```

*it returns string value of them but i still can't figure out it. I had some datatable issues like "Cannot set property 'data' of null" and "Invalid JSON response"*

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        using (Context c = new Context())
        {
            List<Record> recordList = c.Records.ToList<Record>();
            
            return Json(new { data = recordList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

How can i show string value of enum in datatable?

Comment: you need to prepare the json on the serverside, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941712/how-to-get-all-the-enums-in-my-project-as-json

Comment: @johnSmith thanks i did it